# ConditionExpression attribute_not_exists()

Tags: php, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to use ConditionExpression when inserting an item on the database, but it dont work, the php script breaks when the Putitem() function runs.

I want to insert the item if he dont exist.

```
$response = $client->putItem(array(
    'TableName' => 'tablename',
    'Item' => array(
        'serialNumber'   => array('S' => 'test123'),
        'deviceType' => array('S' => '1')
    ),
    'ConditionExpression' => 'attribute_not_exists(serialNumber)'
));
```

I tried to var_dump the $response but the code breaks on the function above.

serialNumber its a Partition Key which should work as intended.

The code below works fine, but he replaces the existing item with new values, which its what i dont want to happen.

```
$response = $client->putItem(array(
    'TableName' => 'tablename',
    'Item' => array(
        'serialNumber'   => array('S' => 'test123'),
        'deviceType' => array('S' => '1')
    )
));
```

Comment: Your first example, the one with the Condition Expression, does it work if the item is not already in the table?

Comment: Yes, if the attritube dont exist, it inserts normaly. I am trying to use a loop to insert multiple values, thats why i need the response to be "The conditional request failed" in order to warn the user how many failed to insert.

Comment: What does "the code breaks" mean? Do you get an error message? What does it say? Be specific.

Comment: When i run ajax request, it gives error 500., When i run the function, it simply dont give any errors, the page dont execute. The same function works if the condition expression is not met. I was also expecting at least an error mensage from the response or some fail mensage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is expected that you are returned a `CondidtionCheckFailedException` when the condition you set evaluates to false. Try wrapping your code in a `try/catch` block to see if it works as expected?

```
try {
$response = $client->putItem(array(
    'TableName' => 'tablename',
    'Item' => array(
        'serialNumber'   => array('S' => 'test123'),
        'deviceType' => array('S' => '1')
    )
));
}
catch(Exception $e) {
  echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: It shows a string, so i had to use a strpos to check if the condition failed, didnt find how handle error message, since the [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Programming.Errors.html#Programming.Errors.MessagesAndCodes) didnt work for me. But try catch worked.